# Is there a finite group that is both 2-Frobenius and Frobenius?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

A finite group G is called a 2-Frobenius group if it has a normal series $1\unlhd H\unlhd K\unlhd G$, where $K$ and $G/H$
are Frobenius groups with kernels $H$ and $K/H$, respectively.

We consider  the relationship between $A=\{2\text{-Frobenius groups}\}$ and $B=\{\text{Frobenius groups}\}$:

> **QUESTION.** Is it $A\cap B=\varnothing$?

Comment: $S_{4}$ is a $2$-Frobenius group which is not a Frobenius group ( with $H$ the normal Klein $4$-subgroup, $K = A_{4}$ and $G/H \cong S_{3}$). Also, $S_{3}$ is a Frobenius group which is not  a $2$-Frobenius group.

Comment: So, is it $A\cap B=\varnothing$?

Comment: @Simon Is it impossible for $A\cap B$ to be nonempty but properly contained in both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin In the beginning, I conjecture any Frobenius group is not  a 2-Frobenius group, any 2-Frobenius group is not  a Frobenius group too. However, I don't prove that. Maybe this is a conclusion in some books, but it is not found.

Comment: @Simon: In the beginning of what? Your question asks: "is every $2$-Frobenius group a Frobenius group, or is every Frobenius group a $2$-Frobenius group, or is it the case that there is no group that is both?" This trilemma is unjustified in the current question; if you were conjecturing that the two sets were disjoint, why would you ask if one is contained in the other?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Sorry, I haven’t figured out the question clearly. I will re-edit.

Comment: Note that Geoff Robinson's comment addresses a prior version of the question, which also asked if all Frobenius groups were 2-Frobenius, or if all 2-Frobenius groups were Frobenius.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Where was the mistake in your deleted proof that $A \cap B = \varnothing$? If the $2$-Frobenius group $G$ was also a Frobenius group, then its kernel would be its Fitting subgroup $H$. So the question becomes can a Frobenius complement be Frobenius group. But it is not hard to see that a Frobenius group must contain a noncyclic subgroup of order $pq$ for (not necessarily distinct) primes $p,q$, which is not possible in a Frobenius complement.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I was going to try to rewrite it. I got a bit confused after the question from the OP. I agree that the original proof was probably correct ( the only issue being whether the Frobenisu kernel is $H$, as you say). I'll try to reinsert it if I have time.

Comment: I think the kernel being $H$ follows easily from the fact that the Frobenius kernel is equal to the Fitting subgroup (this is all assuming finiteness of course).

Comment: Yes, I was implicitly assuming that when I first wrote the answer, but got flustered by the OPs queston. I have put in details now (along similar lines to what you were thinking- I certainly am only dealing with finite groups, which I assume the OP intended).

Comment: I get it. I want to thank all of you for your help.   Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attempt at correction ( or more precisely, justification that original attempt was basically correct): let $G$ be a Frobenius group with kernel $L$. Then $L \leq F(G)$ by Thompson's theorem, so $Z(F(G)) \leq C_{G}(L) \leq L,$ as $L$ is a Frobenius kernel. Then $F(G) \leq C_{G}(Z(F(G)) \leq L,$ so in fact $F(G) = L.$

Now suppose that $ 1 \lhd H \lhd K \lhd G$ with $K$ a Frobenius group with kernel $H$, and $G/H$ a Frobenius group with kernel $K/H$ (ie, that $G$ is also a $2$-Frobenius group). Then $K/H = F(G/H)$ by the argument above, so $F(G) \leq K,$ then $F(G) \leq F(K) \leq F(G)$ and $F(G) = F(K)$. However, $H = F(K),$ again by the argument above, since $K$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $H$. 
Thus $H = F(G)$.

Since $G$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $L$, then we have $L = F(G) = H$.
Hence $G/H$ is isomorphic to a Frobenius complement as well as being a Frobenius group in its own right ( the Frobenius kernel of $G/H$ is $K/H$ and the Frobenius complement is isomorphic to $G/K$).

If $G/H$ has even order, then (since it is a Frobenius complement), it contains a unique involution $tH$ which is central in $G/H,$ so lies in $F(G/H) = K/H$ . This is a contradiction to the fact that $G/H$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $K/H.$ Hence $G/H$ has odd order, and all its Sylow subgroups are cyclic, as it is a Frobenius complement. By elementary transfer, $G/H$ is solvable. It follows that $F(G/H) = K/H$ is a cyclic Hall subgroup of $G/H.$

However, W. Burnside already observed that if $p,q$ are distinct prime divisors of the order of of a Frobenius complement, any subgroup of order $pq$ of the complement is cyclic. If we choose a prime divisor $p$ of $[K:H]$ and a prime divisor $q$ of $[G:K]$, we obtain a contradiction, since $G/H$ can't contain an element of order $pq$ as it's a Frobenius group with kernel $K/H.$ On the other hand, an element of order $q$ in $G/H$ normalizes $\Omega_{1}(O_{p}(K/H)),$ which is cyclic of order $p,$ so $G/H$ does contain a subgroup of order $pq.$

Comment: It's great!  But I don't understand why $G/H$ is supposed as the  Frobenius complement.

Comment: This is now reedited, and Simon's question is answered by the revised answer.